# Cannot deploy xcode project in iphone

Tags: iphone, deployment, xcodebuild

I would need your help if possible please.

I'm trying to deploy axcode project in an iphone. I followed all the steps, but when i try to deploy it i get this message:

Choose a destination with a supported architecture in order to run on this device.

Now, i've read a lot on the internet and i didn't come up with a good choice...
The main settings are:
Deployment Target 3.2
Architectures: Armv7

I am currently trying to install it in a iphone 3...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iphone 3 needs armv6 support im sure,

You can set this in your Target Build Settings in Xcode 
[image]

Check out my screen grab.

Cheers,

LB

Comment: More specifically, iOS 4.2.5 and below requires armv6.